# Issue when migrate from spring 3.2.2 to 4.2.3 Release

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

```
   Trying to upgrade from
 Trying to upgrade from `Spring` 3.2.2 to 4.2.3. Release facing below issue:

        [2/5/16 17:13:54:807 IST] 00000055 webapp I
        com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - 
        [citicomp_war#citicomp.war]:.No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types 
        detected on classpath

        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message -   
        [citicomp_war#citicomp.war]:.Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext

        [2/5/16 17:13:57:930 IST] 00000055 webapp E 
        com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: 
        Exception caught while initializing context: {0}

        org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to 
        parse configuration class 
        [com.citigroup.ces.citicomp.boesdk.datatype.SDKConfig]; nested exception is 
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: Could not open ServletContext resource 
        [/sdk_config.properties]

    Even though I can see the `sdk_config.properites` file.

    **Steps I executed to migration**

    - 1) Application is running successfully with 3.2.2 Release version jars from last one year.
    - 2) As part of migration, as per the suggestion I modified dependencies to 4.2.3 Release and some third party jars like `Jackson` to recommended version.
    - 3) Deployment of war went good, but when is start the application in `WebSphere` after deployment the above issue comes.

    **Technology/software details**

    - IBM websphere 8.0.0 
    - Java 6

    jars i am using
    activation-1.1.jar</br>
    aopalliance-1.0.jar</br>
    asm-3.3.1.jar
    aspectjrt-1.8.6.jar
    aspectjweaver-1.8.6.jar
    avalon-framework-4.1.3.jar
    biarengine-12.3.6.1006.jar
    biplugins-12.3.6.1006.jar
    boconfig-12.3.6.1006.jar
    cafinstall-12.3.6.1006.jar
    cecore-12.3.6.1006.jar
    celib-12.3.6.1006.jar
    ceplugins_client-12.3.6.1006.jar
    ceplugins_core-12.3.6.1006.jar
    ceplugins_cr-12.3.6.1006.jar
    cereports-12.3.6.1006.jar
    cesdk-12.3.6.1006.jar
    cesearch-12.3.6.1006.jar
    cesession-12.3.6.1006.jar
    cglib-2.2.2.jar
    classworlds-1.1.jar
    clientplugins-12.3.6.1006.jar
    com.ibm.ws.runtime.jar
    commons_driver-12.3.6.1006.jar
    commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar
    commons-cli-1.0.jar
    commons-collections-2.1.jar
    commons-digester-1.6.jar
    commons-fileupload-1.2.2.jar
    commons-io-1.4.jar
    commons-logging-1.1.jar
    commons-validator-1.3.1.jar
    corbaidl-12.3.6.1006.jar
    crlov-12.3.6.1006.jar
    crlovexternal-12.3.6.1006.jar
    crlovmanifest-12.3.6.1006.jar
    CrystalCommon2-12.3.6.1006.jar
    cvom_chart_lib_en-12.3.6.1006.jar
    cvom_chart_lib-12.3.6.1006.jar
    cvom-12.3.6.1006.jar
    dfc.jar
    doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar
    ebus405-12.3.6.1006.jar
    ehcache-core-2.4.3.jar
    elf-1.0.jar
    i18n4j-12.3.6.1006.jar
    itext-1.4.5-12.3.6.1006.jar
    jackson-annotations-2.2.3.jar
    jackson-core-2.2.3.jar
    jackson-databind-2.2.3.jar
    javax.inject-1.jar
    jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar
    jsch-0.1.27.jar
    jsse.jar
    jstl-1.2.jar
    jtidy-4aug2000r7-dev.jar
    jtools-12.3.6.1006.jar
    jxl-2.6.jar
    jxlib-12.3.6.1006.jar
    log4j-1.2.15.jar
    logging-12.3.6.1006.jar
    logkit-1.0.1.jar
    mail-1.4.jar
    maven-artifact-2.0.6.jar
    maven-artifact-manager-2.0.6.jar
    maven-core-2.0.6.jar
    maven-error-diagnostics-2.0.6.jar
    maven-filtering-1.0.jar
    maven-model-2.0.6.jar
    maven-monitor-2.0.6.jar
    maven-plugin-api-2.0.6.jar
    maven-plugin-descriptor-2.0.6.jar
    maven-plugin-parameter-documenter-2.0.6.jar
    maven-plugin-registry-2.0.6.jar
    maven-profile-2.0.6.jar
    maven-project-2.0.6.jar
    maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar
    maven-repository-metadata-2.0.6.jar
    maven-resources-plugin-2.5.jar
    maven-settings-2.0.6.jar
    mybatis-3.1.0.jar
    mybatis-ehcache-1.0.3.jar
    mybatis-spring-1.2.0.jar
    ojdbc6-11.2.0.jar
    plexus-build-api-0.0.4.jar
    plexus-container-default-1.0-alpha-9-stable-1.jar
    plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar
    plexus-interpolation-1.13.jar
    plexus-utils-2.0.5.jar
    rasapp-12.3.6.1006.jar
    rascore-12.3.6.1006.jar
    rebean-12.3.6.1006.jar
    rebean.fc-12.3.6.1006.jar
    rebean.wi-12.3.6.1006.jar
    ReportViewer-12.3.6.1006.jar
    serialization-12.3.6.1006.jar
    SL_plugins-12.3.6.1006.jar
    slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
    slf4j-log4j12-1.6.6.jar
    spring-aop-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
    spring-beans-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
    spring-context-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
    spring-context-support-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
    spring-core-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
    spring-expression-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
    spring-jdbc-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar
    spring-jmx-2.0.5.jar
    spring-orm-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-config-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-core-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
    spring-security-web-3.2.3.RELEASE.jar
    spring-tx-3.2.6.RELEASE.jar
    spring-web-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
    spring-webmvc-4.2.3.RELEASE.jar
    sunjce_provider.jar
    URIUtil-12.3.6.1006.jar
    wagon-file-1.0-beta-2.jar
    wagon-http-lightweight-1.0-beta-2.jar
    wagon-http-shared-1.0-beta-2.jar
    wagon-provider-api-1.0-beta-2.jar
    wagon-ssh-1.0-beta-2.jar
    wagon-ssh-common-1.0-beta-2.jar
    wagon-ssh-external-1.0-beta-2.jar
    webreporting-12.3.6.1006.jar
    wilog-12.3.6.1006.jar
    xml-apis-1.0.b2.jar

 above is the list of jars we are using to migrate, please confirm with above
```

below is the application context
below is the application context   using the xsi schema pointing to 4.2
please confirm with below xsi like i am i pointing to the correct xsi 
i am using spring 4.2.3.Release

```
applicationcontext xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
     xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
     xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:env.properties, classpath:sdk_config.properties"/>
```

Comment: The Exception says you're missing /sdk_config.properties. Are you sure it's on your classpath? Say directly in your resources folder?

Comment: thanks for the reply, yes sdk_config.properties file exist on class path.